# Making a new array considered a Dynamic Assignment Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make an array where to keep scores for every user. An example of the array would be `ScoreArray["example@yahoo.com"] = 10`. To do this I need to instantiate the Array first. So I tried something like:

```
ScoreArray = Array.new

    @sugested.each do |gg|
      nr = 0
      @followees.each do |ff|
        if (ff.email == gg.email) then nr = nr + 1
        end
      end
      if(gg.following.count != 0) then
        score = ( nr/@followees.count ) * ( gg.followers.count / gg.following.count)
        ScoreArray[gg.email] = score
        pry.bind
      else score = 0
      end 
    end
```

All this code is inside a `method` called `candidates` . When I try to run `rails server` I get the following error message on the page where I invoke this method :

```
home/flo/Ruby/Licenta/honk_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:45: dynamic constant assignment ScoreArray = Array.new ^
```

Any ideas how can I avoid this problem? And why is it doing this?(from what I've read is because it's inside a method and ruby doesn't like instantiating a "constant" each time a method is called. The thing is , this is not a constant ... for each user that logs in I will have a separate array).

Comment: What is the scope of this array (i think you actually want a hash) supposed to be?

Comment: I did want to make a hash first. But I have to order it by score(the values in it) after, so I decided an Array would be better . The order is necessary because I will have to show Users in order based on that score

Comment: U can try something like this `Hash[actual_hash.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]`, this will give you a hash sorted by values, in your case score is a value

Comment: @Sontya it returns a hash ? And if I do .each on that Hash I get the elements in order(by score) ?

Comment: If you don't want a constant, why make it a constant? (if it starts with an uppercase letter it's a constant)

Comment: because I am new to ruby and I never thought that if a variable is written with an uppercase letter it means that it is constant :) do post it as the right answer lol :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby a leading capital letter denotes a constant - if you don't want a constant then start with a lowercase letter (if a local variable isn't sufficient for your purpose, consider an instance variable)

In addition arrays can't be used as you show them

```
some_array[gg.email]
```

Will raise an exception if `gg.email` is a string

Comment: true indeed :P I changed it back to a hash and did as Sontya told me :P .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
score_hash = Hash.new
score_hash[gg.email] = score
sorted_hash = Hash[score_hash.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
```

Comment: dynamic constant assignment ScoreHash = Hash.new it still has the same dynamic constant assignment error